# Add a file to a database by its path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, store

I have a subroutine, which generates a .mp4 file and calls a ruby script afterwards with a unique identifier of the file.
The file looks something like this one the filesystem:

```
/opt/program/records/123345_record.mp4
```

The number in the filename represents the unique modifier, the ruby script knows. Now I want to store this generated file in the database. I already prepared the schema file with the corresponding migration files so the table has an extra column for the file.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_04_12_123013) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.binary "file", limit: 104857600
  end

end
```

But how can I store the file in the row defined in the model/migration file?
In the articles_controller.rb I could define a method, that can be called like this:

```
def add_file

end
```

This is not sufficient enough, but I don't know, how to fill the new field "file" with the data which is currently stored on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `rake` script and run it from terminal.

https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/02/ruby-rake/

Comment: Why do I need a taskrunner for this problem? Isn't there proper way to add a file to the object like myarticle.add_file("path/to/file") in standard ruby?

Comment: you want fill a new field in database after you created it, it's like a callback after migrations, you can do this on migration, but it a bad way. Or i'm wrong understood your problem. Did you have a model and you added new field, its one way do it, run a script from rake or rails console. If you create a new model and want add a path on mp4 file after you create a instance of model you can do it by `after_create` model callback. 
`after_create :add_file
def add_file
  update(file: 'path/to/file.mp4')
end
`